# Multiple URL requests to API without getting error from urllib2 or requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib, httplib2

I am trying to get data from different APIs. They are received in JSON format, stored in SQLite and afterwards parsed.

The issue I am having is that when sending many requests I eventually receive an error, even if I am using `time.sleep` between requests.

## Usual approach

My code looks like the one below, where this would be inside a loop and the url to be opened would be changing:

```
base_url = 'https://www.whateversite.com/api/index.php?'
custom_url = 'variable_text1' + & + 'variable_text2' 

url = base_url + custom_urls #url will be changing

time.sleep(1)
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

This runs thousands of times inside the loop. The problem comes after the script has been running for a while (up to a couple of hours), then I get the following errors or similar ones:

```
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

or

```
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 437, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1172, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I believe this happens because the modules throw an error at some point if used too often in a short period of time.

From what I've read in many different threads about [which module is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module), I think for my needs all would work and the main lever to choose one is that it can open as many url's as possible. In my experience, `urllib` and `urllib2` are better than `requests` for that, as `requests` crashed in less time.

Assuming that I do not want to increase the waiting time used in `time.sleep`, these are the solutions I thought so far:

## Possible solutions?

### A

I thought of combining all different modules. That would be:

- Start, for instance, with `requests`.
- After a specific time or when error is thrown, switch automatically
  to `urllib2`
- After a specific time or when error is thrown, switch automatically to other modules (such as `httplib2` or `urllib`) or back to `requests`
- And so on...

### B

Use `try .. except` block to handle that exception, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer).

### C

I've also read about [sending multiple requests at once or in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512646/how-to-speed-up-api-requests). I don't know how that exactly works and if it could actually be useful

---

However, I am not convinced about any of these solutions.

Can you think of any more elegant and/or efficient solution to deal with this error?

*I'm with Python 2.7*

Comment: Perhaps close the object returned by `urlopen()` or `requests` to close the connection?

Comment: What is the url it happens on?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm not sure if I understood the question: the url is to an API. 
It is to get info about travel journeys, so you typically need to give at lease origin_id, destination_id and date. 
That is for example `url = serviceurl + segment1 + '&' + segment2 + '&' + segment3` where the segments will be different.
This url returns pure JSON.

Comment: @zachyee , how can I close the object returned? In that case, following the code I wrote in the explanation, that object would be `data`, correct?

Comment: The socket will be closed automatically, I mean what is the actual url that you are using, is it a public api or are you scraping an internal api

Comment: https://www.DeinBus.de/fapi/trips/index.php?departure=XXX&arrival=XXX&departuredatetime=XXX&timerange=XXX

The documentation can be found here: https://www.deinbus.de/affiliate/dokumentation.php but, you need to be registered and provide username and password to really get access to the data.

Comment: @JoanMM You would end up doing something like `response = urllib.urlopen(url)` `data = response.read()` `response.close()` Once it goes out of scope, it is eligible for garbage collection, but doing it explicitly might help since you're attempting to reach a lot of urls in a small amount of time. Even better would be to use a contextmanager (with keyword). More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522636/should-i-call-close-after-urllib-urlopen

Comment: Thanks @zachyee. Unfortunately, I tried and still got the error (this time it was thrown quite fast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I was not convinced, I ended up trying to implement the `try .. except` block and I'm quite happy with the result:

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = response.read()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        response.close() #as suggested by zachyee in the comments

        #code to save data in SQLite database

    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        print '***** urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known> *****'
        #save error in SQLite
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Errors (error_type, error_ts, url_queried)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', ('urllib2.URLError', timestamp, url))
        conn.commit()
        time.sleep(30) #give it a small break
```

The script did run until the end.

From thousands of requests I got 8 errors, that were saved in my database with its related URL. This way I can try to retrieve those url's again afterwards, if needed.